# Unable to use Angular custom elements with other Angular apps

Tags: angular, web-component, angular-components, custom-element

I have made an angular custom element and concatenated all its files to one file and it works fine. However if i try to include the the Angular custom element with another angular application it throws the following error.

```
zone.js:32 Uncaught Error: Zone already loaded.
at zone.js:32
at zone.js:644
at zone.js:9
at Object../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js (zone.js:12)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
at Object../src/polyfills.ts (polyfills.ts:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
at Object.1 (polyfills.ts:76)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:43)
```

and

```
core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'upload-service' is not a known element:
 1. If 'upload-service' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
 2. If 'upload-service' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the 
'@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<upload-service
baseUrl="http://localhost:33089/"
levelId="e92fa5fc-8a37-4d2a-8936-8d115d448bc1"
"): ng:///UserManagementModule/UsersList.html@0:0
Error: Template parse errors:
'upload-service' is not a known element:
1. If 'upload-service' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'upload-service' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the 
'@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<upload-service
baseUrl="http://localhost:33089/"
levelId="e92fa5fc-8a37-4d2a-8936-8d115d448bc1"
"): ng:///UserManagementModule/UsersList.html@0:0
at syntaxError (compiler.js:1021)
at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse 
(compiler.js:14830)
at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate 
(compiler.js:24018)
at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate 
(compiler.js:24005)
at compiler.js:23948
at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
at 
JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents 
(compiler.js:23948)
at compiler.js:23858
at Object.then (compiler.js:1012)
```

I have tried fixing this issue by the following,

- Zone Strategy (as the zones of the custom element and my Angular application is colliding with each other)
- CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA

Unfortunately both did not work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved this. For those who come across this issue in the future.

Since i was trying to use angular custom element inside another angular app it was giving Zone conflict.

All you need to know is the Host application who are trying to add a custom element should have their zone.js of version above **0.9.0**

Also make sure you add your custom element using JavaScript and not as a web-component.

```
   var serviceElement = document.createElement('service');
   var serviceHolder = document.getElementById('service-holder');

   serviceElement.setAttribute('baseurl', 'http://localhost:33089/');
   serviceHolder.appendChild(serviceElement);
```

As a web-component, your host application will start throwing error saying its not a known element.

Hope this solves your issue.

Happy Coding!